# adding template type in function definition

Tags: c++, templates

I understand the syntax and usage of function template.

But can some explain what does the following syntax means and what is the usage of it.

```
enum class Building_type {CONDO, TWON_HOME, SINGLE_FAMILY};

struct BuildingInfo {
    bool old;
    string city;
    string state;
    bool sold;
}

template<Building_type p>
BuildingInfo Building_query (bool) {
    return BuildingInfo{false, "NA", "NA", false};
}

template<>
BuildingInfo Building_query<Building_type::CONDO>(bool) {
     return BuildingInfo{true, "San-Diego", "CA", false};
}
```

More specifically, does the compiler detects which definition should be returned by checking the passing Building_type in a function call ?

like

`Building_query<Building_type::CONDO> (true);`

Comment: The compiler chooses the implementation to use based on the template parameter, if that's what you're asking....

Comment: It is called *function template specialization*, the second definition is a special case of the first definition used when user chose the specified type `Building_type::CONDO`.

Comment: So, although the template doesn't actually _use_ that parameter in any way, this trick  does provide a (slightly convoluted) mechanism to tell the compiler - at the call site - how you want `Building_query` to be called. But I think this code is pointless and an abuse of template specialisation.  It's totally obscure and totally unnecessary - if you want to call `Building_query` with a particular set of parameters then just do it.  Unless all your CONDO's are in San Diego, perhaps.  Where did the code come from?  Is it intended as some sort of demonstration (although what of escapes me)?

Comment: And now, people who know much more than me will be queuing up to shoot me down, because they can probably see a reason that I can't :)

Comment: @PaulSanders: The possible advantage to template specialization is that the next layer up can also be parameterized and write only a single implementation that finds either implementation automatically.

Comment: @BenVoigt OK, I can see how that might work.  I got inspired enough to write up an answer, don't know if it's really worth that much though.

Comment: @PaulSanders: I tend to agree with you that in this case the benefits are unlikely to outweigh the added complexity.  I just wanted to share the thing that wouldn't work with ordinary functions with appropriate distinct names.

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, got it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, well, since @Ben called me out on my comment (I knew *someone* would), I thought I'd write up what I hope might be some useful observations.  What that code does, and how it does it, has already been adequately covered in the comments so I'll skip that part.  The question in my mind, is *why* write it that way in the first place?  As I said, it's a pretty esoteric thing to do, so doing it at all needs to be justified.

So first of all, since I'm being so opinionated, what are the alternatives?

Apart from doing the obvious and just constructing a `BuildingInfo` object with the parameters you want whenever you need one, you might prefer to write a regular function (as opposed to a function template) along these lines:

```
BuildingInfo build_condo_in_san_diego() { return BuildingInfo{true, "San-Diego", "CA", false}; }
```

simple, straightforward, and obvious what you're up to to anyone reading the code.  If you want, you can put the function in a header file to inline it, and then it doesn't cost you anything.

Or maybe you want something more like this:

```
BuildingInfo build_dwelling_in_california (Building_type type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case Building_type::CONDO:          
            return BuildingInfo{true, "San-Diego", "CA", false};
        case Building_type::TWON_HOME:
            return BuildingInfo{true, "Los Angeles", "CA", false};
        // ...
    }
}
```

which would localise the types of dwellings that you build in different cities in a single place in the code.

So, if we look back at the code you originally posted, why write it that way?

Well, I thought about this while walking round the block earlier and I realised that it is, in effect, just a compile-time `switch`, and as such it's actually pretty clever.  Too clever, in fact, unless performance is paramount, in which case it's a useful trick to have up your sleeve.  But in this example, it's not.  A much better example would have been something like `handle_interrupt_when_hard_disk_ready()`, say.

All of which - the rationale, I mean - should have been explained to the reader wherever it was you got the code from.  But maybe it was and you didn't share it with us, I'd love know.